Use abilities hardcoded instead of abilities table
My Laravel app uses silber/bouncer package for permissions management. All my abilities are stored in a mysql table, I'm looking for a solution to make them hardcoded, instead of keep them in a database. 
Since bouncer is totally eloquent based, I created my ExtendedAbility model with sushi package to make all the abilities defined in this model.
When I tell bouncer to use another model for abilities at Authorize middleware I got SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: roles :
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $ability): mixed
{
    Bouncer::useAbilityModel(ExtendedAbility::class);

    if (Bouncer::can($ability)) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    abort(403);
}

Since sushi package under the hood creates SQLITE database for each model, the query fails because laravel searches for the table roles at sqlite, not mysql. 
The main question, is that actually possible to keep all the abilities hardcoded?

What is the content of the ExtendedAbility class , did you define  protected $table ?

@elemes, why do I need to set the table name? I want to keep my abilities hardcoded but eloquent like. That's why I tried to use sushi package. But it's not just a question about sushi package, is it possible to have my abilities hardcoded with bouncer permissions package?

according to this https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/releases/tag/v0.0.22
you have to specify the table name as the other tables rely on this relationship (reference). reason for asking for the content of the ExtendedAbility class.

I understand how the bouncer works and I had it functioning correctly for a long of time. But now I'm looking for a possible solution to replace the bouncer's table abilities and make all my abilities hardcoded. Bouncer package relies on Eloquent models so I came to idea that maybe I can create eloquent model with all my abilities hardcoded and just make a trick. That's why I mentioned sushi package since it provides something similar I need. But no luck @elemes
